# Selecting data in a multiuser environment

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I'm building a crm based system that will be utilized simultaneously by about 10 users.

What is the best method to prevent the same record being open, used and saved against if it is already open by another users.

I'm trying to second guess the chance scenario of user 2 overwriting user 1s changes with in a few seconds opened.

Comment: also - who is correct?  if you change a row - and i change it tomorrow, is that ok?  now shrink tomorrow to shorter and shorter times.. what does that really mean?

Comment: Do you know when user starts editing some row? Or you just have a list of records on a page and user can edit any of those after page is opened?

Comment: At the moment this is all hypothetical but in referring to the latter.

Comment: Not sure why it's been close by stack overflow - I may not of used exact syntax but it's definitly a valid question that I need help on.

Answer (score 2):

I see few ways:

1) Just add a timestamp column to your database and post it on a form in hidden field. Once someone save a record after editing - you can compare timestamp value received from client with one currently available in database. If those are equal - save changes and update timestamp column. Otherwise(someone just edited that record) - do not save changes and handle that situation somehow.
Problem here is that you need to get a timestamp value from database and compare it. During that time (after you requested a value, but not yet saved changes) someone may update record. That time frame will be just a few milliseconds and because of that I think it could be ignored.

I had no chance to do something like that, but as I remember, database usually can lock a row somehow. So any read attempt will be stopped until lock is not removed. Suppose, this way you may avoid problem I mentioned above.

2) if you can control session state, you can mark a record as being edited after someone open it for editing. That mark can contain a session ID of an editor. Once editing is done - you'll remove that mark (anyone can edit it again). But someone may start editing and leave page opened. So, you need to check if session is still alive. Once it is dead - mark a record for editing.

Comment: I like option 2. In terms of checking if session is dead - is this a periodical check using cron or is it a check made during login for example.

Comment: You can store session in database. Once it is there - it is really easy to check if session is died or not(you know session ID, last time session were used, session lifetime period and current time). But once it is a default session storage - it is harder.I'm not even sure if it is possible to figure out if session is alive for sure(in PHP).

Comment: You can also track the timestamp and editing userid independent of the session, then check the userid when trying to load-for-edit or save and respond appropriately if the userids don't match. Then add a cron job into the mix to expire stale locks (by NULLing out the timestamp and userid).

Comment: But in such case you may change approach a little. Just update timestamp column for a user each time some request is done(by a user). And write an editor ID instead of session ID. That way you will be able to check when the last request were done by an editor. Once it was more than $sessio_lifetime minutes/seconds/hours ago - mark a record as free. You can do that any time someone is reading some editable record.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess I was hoping for a simple database function to do it. Im just starting out with Postgres and understand it has constraints which could apply to this situation

Comment: I'm afraid constraints is not what can help you. If you are talking about a thing that I know like constraints - it is usually just a way to tell database if it can accept some kind of data (for instance, only 1,2 and 3 for some column is acceptable). But something like you want - that is not from a list of database engine  tasks.